# Get song duration from an mp3 file in a script?

Tags: powershell, mp3

I am trying to list some of my mp3 files with Powershell.

I have tried

```
ls C:\test | Format-List -Property Name,Length
```

which gives me

```
Name   : testfile.mp3
Length : 10058533
```

The length is the size of the file which I don't care for at this moment.

Knowing that I can choose duration in File Explorer for a column heading I thought to 
re-write the above as

```
ls C:\test | Format-List -Property Name,Duration
```

but what I get is

```
Name   : testfile.mp3
```

How can I tell Powershell to return the minutes and seconds for the duration? Or even just the seconds. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the length of an mp3, probably the easiest way is to make use of what explorer uses, a Shell objekt.

I'm afraid I don't have a one-liner for you, but you can always make a script that you call.

```
$path = 'M:\Musikk\awesome_song.mp3'
$shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$folder = Split-Path $path
$file = Split-Path $path -Leaf
$shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder)
$shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file)

write-host $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27);
```

More information can be found here:
http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2011/01/07/organizing-videos-and-music.aspx

Edit: The reason this method is necessary is because the length information resides with the other metadata of the file.

Comment: I wasn't asking for one-liner so no deduction there :) And yes this does give me what I am asking for now I need to loop it for multiples files :) Thanks