# How can I extract metadata (particularly length) from a folder of many audio files in Windows 7?

Tags: audio, metadata, wmv

I have a folder with hundreds of audio files, and the main information I want is the length. I can view it in Windows explorer, but I don't know how to extract it to put it into an Excel file so I can analyze it.

Preference would be for a programmatic method. I personally work in stats software (R, Stata, SAS), but could probably make something else work given enough instruction (and I have access to programmers who know other "real" programming languages).

Free or cheap software might work, too, but I'm working in a restricted data environment, so not having to install something is best.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get song duration from an mp3 file in a script?](http://superuser.com/questions/704575/get-song-duration-from-an-mp3-file-in-a-script)

Comment: Thanks, Techie007. I checked out that link, but I don't think my question is a duplicate because that on only talks about a Windows PowerShell option. I've never used PowerShell myself, and don't even know where to start with the code they've given. I'll save it for if I have to ask a programmer to help though. Thanks.

Comment: You said: "but could probably make something else work given enough instruction (and I have access to programmers who know other "real" programming languages)."  you left your question broad, and while that question centres on PowerShell (and the answer could easily be adapted to VBS or alike as well) it's still the same problem/question (IMO).  If you had specifically said "how can I do this is XYZ" then I'd probably consider it to be a different question. But regardless, hope that link helps, and it takes more than just my vote to close. ;)

Comment: Any lead is helpful. Thanks again. I've always wonder how closing a topic works. I'm a newer uses and haven't read all the documentation yet.