# Batch Script: calculation how long a sound file

Tags: windows, audio, batch, batch-file, vbscript

file WAV or MP3,

i need to create a `SET` value to calculation how long a sound file.

like:

```
echo %VideoTime% Minutes.
Pause > nul
```

OUTPUT:

2.32 Minutes.

i know it is a hard one to make this.

or not idk but i know; this is very objectionable request.

where i need to use this?

i am trying to make a Music Video Player program with CMD.

crazy? yep it is. all script done. but one think is not.

when the music end, this is not refreshing music or not playing next music.

help here please*

Comment: Use ffmpeg,ffprobe or mediainfo to obtain .wav/.mp3 duration.

Comment: [Get song duration from an mp3 file in a script?](https://superuser.com/q/704575/241386)